# passing data in nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, function

i'm a beginner in javascript and i tried to learn about function that called inside a function which redefine a value of a variable. Here's the code

```js
var a;

function app2(a) {
  var a = 8;
  return a
}

function app(a) {
  var a = 7;
  app2(a)
  return a
}
console.log(app(a));
```

when i run code, it still show 7 as the output. i thought it will be 8 because i've called the function `app2` in the `app` function. why the value doesn't change into 8? and what should i do update the variable value inside the nested function? thanks in advance

Comment: How can you expect `8` here since you can only get `8` if you are taking the return value of the function `app2` and return it from `app`.

Comment: Each function body (ie: scope) has its own "version" of the `a` variable, it is not shared (as you're declaring the `a` variable with `var` inside your functions)

Comment: @decpk he is a new contributor and says that he is beginning to js. and the question isn't that hard to understand, he calls `app2` in `app` and expects this function to modify the `a` in the `app`.

Comment: thanks for your answer i've solved it

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can only get `8` if you are taking the value of `app2` and using it inside `app`.

Variables declare with `var` keyword are function scoped and they are not visible outside of that particular function in which it is declared.

`a` declared in `app2` is not visible inside `app` unless you are not returning the value from `app2` and not using the return value from `app2` inside `app`(Both condition should be satisfied to use it)

```js
var a;

function app2(a) {
  var a = 8;
  return a;
}

function app(a) {
  var a = 7;
  a = app2(a);  // reassign the returned value from app2
  return a;
}
console.log(app(a));
```

**2)** If you are returning it and not capturing it, then It's no use. You can also do as:

```js
var a;

function app2(a) {
  var a = 8;
  return a;
}

function app(a) {
  var a = 7;
  return app2(a); // Directly return the value of app2 returned value
}
console.log(app(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main culprit of what you are seeing is that you are naming the arguments of the functions `a` and also the global is named `a`.
When experimenting with this you would expect `a = 8` when all `var` keywords are removed except for the global one. This does not happen because the argument, named `a`, is shadowing the global `var a`. When you use the `var` keyword locally in a function you are essentially telling javascript you want to declare a local function-scoped `var a`, and not reference the global `var a`, so this way any changes stay in the function scope.

Check this snippet out:

```js
var a;

function app2(b) { // changed argument name from `a` to `b`
  a = 8; // removed var keyword here
  return a
}

function app(b) { // changed argument name from `a` to `b`
  a = 7; // removed var keyword here
  app2(a)
  return a
}
console.log(app(a)); // output: 8
```